# INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Can not select a person account: [AccountId]

Tags: unit-test

My test class for inserting contact is

```
static testmethod void invoicetest(){

string strrecord = [select id from RecordType where SobjectType='Account' AND IsPersonType=True limit 1].id;
        system.debug('strrrrr'+strrecord);

        Account acc = new Account(firstName='test',LastName='Acc',Recordtypeid=strrecord);
        insert acc;
        contact con = new contact(firstname='Test',LastName='Contact',Salutation='Mr',Accountid=acc.id);
        insert con;
```

Then I'm getting error as System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Can not select a person account: [AccountId]

How to come out of this!!!!!!!!!

My Apex Class is

```
conlist = new contact[0];
con.lastname = billing.billinglastname;
con.firstname = billing.billinglastname;
conlist.add(con);
 if(con.lastname != null){
                  insert conlist;   //getting error here   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When working with `Person Accounts` you do not need to set the `Contact` separately; that is all handled automatically by Salesforce. Just create a `Person Account` and use that for testing:

```
static testmethod void invoicetest(){

   RecordType myRecordType = [select id from RecordType where SobjectType='Account' AND IsPersonType=True limit 1];

   Account acc = new Account(
     FirstName='test',
     LastName='Acc',
     Recordtypeid=myRecordType.Id);
   insert acc;
}
```

**Edit**: Modified SOQL for retrieving RecordType.

**Update**

Your Apex class is dealing with `Contacts`, your test class is trying to assign `Contacts` to `Accounts`, but your question is relating to `Person Accounts`. I believe both your Apex class and the tests should only be creating `Accounts` with your `Person Account` Record Type.

Comment: If I don't insert contact then I'm getting error as System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [LastName]

Comment: Your code specifically mentions setting the LastName field, though. This is pretty much exactly what I use in my unit tests, too.

Comment: Getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Try creating it like this instead:

```
string strrecord = [select id from RecordType where SobjectType='Account' AND IsPersonType=True limit 1].id;

Account Acc = new Account(
  RecordTypeID=strrecord,
  FirstName='jane',
  LastName='doe');

insert Acc;
```

**Update**

After re-reading the [Person Account Tips and Cheatsheet](http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_B2C_cheatsheet.pdf) I noticed it specifically says that Person Accounts do not have a Contacts related list (Usage Notes, pages 2.)

Comment: added my Apex class can u check once

Comment: Have you given visibility to this record type to your profile?. I would double check that.

Answer (score 0):

In the newer APIs, the Contact is completely read-only if it is attached to a Person Account. In fact, the Contact record is only a "convenience" for the underlying data model. So in your test you don't need to create and insert a separate Contact and try and bind it to the Account. Insert the test Account and the test Contact will just be there.